# Difference between VS2012 Development ASP.NET Page and IIS Deployed Page Getting Username

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

So i am attempting to get the username of the person currently logged into the system.

While developing in VS2012 and running the debugger having it run its VS Development Server, i can use Environment.Username to get this.

But when i deploy to an IIS server I get the username ASP.NET v4.0, which i am pretty sure is because im using the ApplicationPoolIdentity in IIS for my Site(using IIS 7.5)

My goal is for the website to be accessible to anyone on the domain without requiring a login or anything, but still be able to grab their username so that i can give certain users access to administrative features and create SQL queries to build tables based on their login.
These user names and groups are stored in a database separate from the website, not part of ASP.NET forms logins or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Environment.Username will give you the application pool identity. Since it is 'you' who is running VS, it will give your name on the development machine.

You should implement `windows authentication` and use `HttpContext.Current.User` to access the current user.